# What ways are there to call a constructor in C++?

Tags: c++

//I have a for loop that should construct an array of a certain class "Line" from two arrays of floats

```
for (int i=0; i<length; i++) Linearray[i](a[i], b[i]);
```

//my constructor function for line is:

```
pine::pine(float a, float b) {
   st = a;
   e = b;
}
```

//the error I'm getting is that I have no call operator defined.
//It's a little complicated to explain, so say all I can use is this constructor to fill that array.
//also assume arrays a and b are full of floats.

Comment: `std::vector<Line> Linearray; for (...) Linearray.emplace_back(a[i], b[i]);`

Comment: How is `Linearray` defined? Please post an [MCVE].

Comment: Formally speaking, *you* can't call a constructor at all. It is called on your behalf when an object is to be created.

Comment: Please define exactly what  `Linearray` is, because it matters in that context, as what you mean might be an assignment, not typical construction.

Comment: @molbdnilo formally you can,  `Line instance; instance = Line(a,b);` would be a direct call, leading to creation of temporal object (all questions why consider this a constructor call direct to Mr. Bjarne, please).

Answer (score 4):

This `Linearray[i](a[i], b[i]);` tries to call the call operator `operator()()` (see also [What are C++ functors and their uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses)) from the `Line` class (which you probably haven't defined, hence the error) at the ith element in that list. You'd need to assign a new instance to call a constructor there:

```
Linearray[i] = Line(a[i], b[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is already answered by Timo. Here is another way to achieve same goal

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Line{
  private:
    int start, end;

  public:
  Line(){}

  Line(float a, float b) {
     start = a;
     end = b;
  }

};


int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  int N = 5;
  Line * arr = (Line*)malloc(sizeof(Line) * N);

  for(auto i=0; i<N; i++){
    arr[i] = Line(5,6);
  }

}
```

Comment: Or use placement new to avoid the temporary